Textjoin with header values
I would appreciate your assistance in resolving a small issue..
Link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_jOn0vyv6osaoppeU9TXX1boOlZbnoCFy3eWsddP7uc/edit?usp=sharing
I am using the below formula but the result is not as expected.
Formula:
=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" : ",TOCOL(IF(B6:J6<>"",B5:J6,),1))) 

Result:
WHEEL LOADER : FORKLIFT : CAT 966 H /// CAT 966 G : CAT DP100NZ /// DP70NA /// DP50K1 /// CAT 966 H /// CAT 966 G /// CAT 966 F

Expected Result:
WHEEL LOADER :  CAT 966 H /// CAT 966 G /  FORKLIFT :  CAT DP100NZ /// DP70NA /// DP50K1 /// CAT 966 H /// CAT 966 G /// CAT 966 F


It would be nice if you define how inputs convert to outputs. Alternatively, please try to use minimal examples when you rely on only examples in defining the transformation you need. (There are a lot texts in the example that other users do not need.)


Modifying your formula to:
=textjoin(" /  ",1,arrayformula(if(B6:J6<>"",B$5:J$5&" :  "&B6:J6,)))



Use:
=arrayformula(join(" : ",TOCOL(IF(B6:J6<>"",B$5:J$5 &": "&B6:J6,),1)))

short explanation:

TOCOL(IF(B6:J6<>"",B$5:J$5 &": "&B6:J6  will glue the header with the details (if the details are not empty)
This ends in a , to return an empty result, so JOIN will not add an extra " : "

